# How to start a Cron job from within a cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cron

I am making an `Android/iOS` app using `cordova framework`.

I need to periodically call a `javascript` function that pulls some data from the `server` and refreshes the local `storage` of the app (PUSH from server is not possible in my case). This should happen even if the `app` is not active.

Is there any way in which this can be done?

Comment: You can use background refresh mode on iOS.  You don't have any control over the exact execution period and I don't know if it is available in a Cordova app

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?